report when the unique status changes for a number and version
I'm not sure how to explain it so hopefully this example will.
Here is my data:
NOTE: row_num is added for reference only. it is not part of the data
row_num, id, number, version, status, date
1, 99999, CDC800, v8.5, F, 2024-02-05
2 ,99904, CDC800, v8.5, F, 2023-12-07
3, 98923, CDC800, v8.5, F, 2023-10-26
4, 97999, CDC800, v8.5, F, 2023-9-13
5, 96900, CDC800, v8.5, C, 2023-7-31
6, 96844, CDC800, v8.5, F, 2023-03-02
7, 95000, CDC800, v8.5, F, 2022-09-19
8, 97500, CDC800, v9.2, C, 2023-03-20
9, 67900, CDC800, v12.0,F, 2024-01-01
10,88777, CDC800, v20.2,F, 2022-05-15

sorted by number, version, date DESC
rows 1 through 4 need to be a single row with max date
row 5 remains the same
rows 6 and 7 need to be a single row with max date
rows 8, 9, and 10 need to remain the same.
1, 99999, CDC800, v8.5, F, 2024-02-05
5, 96900, CDC800, v8.5, C, 2023-7-31
6, 96844, CDC800, v8.5, F, 2023-03-02
8, 97500, CDC800, v9.2, C, 2023-03-20
9, 67900, CDC800, v12.0,F, 2024-01-01
10,88777, CDC800, v20.2,F, 2022-05-15

When I group by number, version, status it of course includes rows 1 through 5 and 6. I need row 6 to stand alone because the status changed to F for a short while.
If I use window functions such as ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION number, version, status ORDER BY date) ... or some version of that ... it just continues to number. Rows 1 through 4 get number 1 through 4 and row 6 gets the numbered 5.
I need fresh eyes. I think I'm over thinking this?

Your data is not sorted by version number: v8.5 is between v6.2 and 12.0.

This breaks on changes in the status column within the same number and version as order by date:
with breaks as (
    select *,
        case when
             lead(status, 1, 'X') over (
                 partition by number, version order by date) <> status
             then 1 end as keep
    from T
)
select * from breaks where keep = 1;

All the necessary values are together in the rows marked for keeping.

Thank you shawnt00. this is what I was looking for.
I used LAG instead of LEAD and for the  windows I used
'(PARTITION BY number, version ORDER BY number, version, date DESC)'

@AWEInCA I don't think you want those columns as partitions. You definitely don't need them both in partition by and order by.

The number and version need to be kept together and sorted by date desc. I want the most recent status at the top. The dates could arbitrarily be changed for any number version combination. The window functions are still relatively new for me. It didn't seem to work unless I used them in both the Partition and Order by

@AWEInCA I had misread some of your date values. I see what's going on now.
